# CALayerInvalidGeometry CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Application getting crashed when rendering UIview to image
Code for rendering view to image

```
- (UIImage*)imageOfSelf
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0);

    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *imageOfSelf = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageOfSelf;
}
```

Getting this error

> CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; 1.25987e-321 nan]. Layer:
> <CALayer:0x2834f8580; position = CGPoint (0 0); bounds = CGRect (0 0;
> 0 0); delegate = <UIView: 0x10d425820; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer =
> <CALayer: 0x2834f8580>>; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; >

Similar kind of question is already there but that is not solving my issue.

Comment: did you check the your frame? just a hunch, I think it may not be initialized properly.

Comment: @Joshua it should return nil image if the frame is not correct 
I think I'm missing something

Comment: I think it will try to render then error out. maybe you can try adding a fixed frame first to try it out and check if that solves your problem

Comment: Let me check with this

Comment: did that helped?

Comment: I haven't checked yet, Will let you know if this solves my issue